# Which is the correct type-hint for a byte encoded dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, types

I have a dictionary were the keys are dictionaries encoded in bytestrings:

```py
mydict = {
   b'{"key 1": 3, "key 2": 6}': 'my first value',
   b'{"key 1": 2, "key 2": 7}': 'my second value',
}
```

And I would like to know how to write the type hint.
In my head it would make sense something like:

```py
from typing import Dict, ByteString

mydict: Dict[ByteString[Dict[str, int]], str] = {
   b'{"key 1": 3, "key 2": 6}': 'my first value',
   b'{"key 1": 2, "key 2": 7}': 'my second value',
}
```

But I get `TypeError: typing.ByteString is not a generic class`
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's simply `dict[bytes, str]` - Python doesn't understand the structure of the `bytes`.

In the same vein, the type of `"6"` is string, not "string that contains an integer", and `"(1, 2)"` is a simple string as well, not a string that contains a tuple of integers.

Maybe the closest thing to "typing a string" are [template literal strings in TypeScript](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1-beta/#template-literal-types), but it's still not the same. A string is just a string - it can't be parametrised.

Comment: Could I now write `dict[bytes, str]` for the correct typing? I am curious as to distinction between `Bytes` and `bytes`

Comment: @CharlieG yes, and it is the preferred way as of https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/ where it states "Importing those from typing is deprecated". As for the distinction between `Bytes` and `bytes` I think the only one is that `bytes` serves a dual purpose: type hinting and actual use.